# `BlockchainEvents` reliability and differences on a syncing node

Tags: blockchain-events, streams

On an actively syncing parachain node, I observed an [import_notification_stream](https://crates.parity.io/sc_client_api/client/trait.BlockchainEvents.html#tymethod.import_notification_stream) subscriber is not notified.

In the same code context, if I subscribe to the [finality_notification_stream](https://crates.parity.io/sc_client_api/client/trait.BlockchainEvents.html#tymethod.finality_notification_stream) instead, I get inmediately notified.

- When reading the documentation I noticed that `Not guaranteed to be fired for every imported block` is mentioned. What is the reason to not being guaranteed?
- In a syncing node, can the number of active `import_notification_sinks` affect on notification delivery guarantees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When reading the documentation I noticed that Not guaranteed to be fired for every imported block is mentioned. What is the reason to not being guaranteed?

When your node is fully synced and you are only syncing at the tip of the chain you will get all notifications. However, when you are doing a major sync, aka syncing from genesis you will not get any notifications. Otherwise you would get like thousands of notifications in a short amount of time. This is just some fairly simple [heuristic](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a0b287557cc032e1c224a5e1dbb82f485c085d0b/client/service/src/client/client.rs#L581-L588):

```
        let make_notifications = match origin {
            BlockOrigin::NetworkBroadcast | BlockOrigin::Own | BlockOrigin::ConsensusBroadcast =>
                true,
            BlockOrigin::Genesis | BlockOrigin::NetworkInitialSync | BlockOrigin::File => false,
        };
```

> In a syncing node, can the number of active import_notification_sinks affect on notification delivery guarantees?

No the number of active sinks doesn't influence the delivery guarantees.

Comment: Thank you @bkchr :)